# passing a value from a method to another method

Tags: angular

I try to pass a value that I grab from button

`<button mat-button type="button" (click)="getOrderid(booking?.order_id)">Accept Job</button>`

I do the console log on second method, it didn't return any value inside my second method
here is both my method

```
getOrderid(order_id?: any){
    console.log (order_id);
  }
signupdatebooking() {
    var user_id = localStorage.getItem('user_id');
    console.log (order_id);
    const body = {
      id: ,
      sprayer_id: user_id,

    };
}
```

Comment: How are you storing the id in the first method?

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich I put it inside first function

Comment: You're logging it, not storing it.

Comment: I referring to order_id not the user_id

Comment: What a coincidence, me too.

Comment: Either create a local variable and assign the value of order_id, whose type probably shouldn't be any, to it or use some kind of service for storage. Then you can reuse it in the second method. I also suggest working on your typescript knowledge. Followed by delving into dependency injection with Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a method like this:

```
getOrderid(order_id?: any){
    console.log (order_id);
  }
```

The argument, `order_id` is local to the method and will not be available to code outside of the getOrderid method.

When you try to access the the `order_id` variable inside the `signupdatebooking()` it looks at variables defined locally to that method and sees none, thus cannot access it.

Based on your HTML code, I would probably just access the `booking.order_id` directly, like this:

```
signupdatebooking() {
    var user_id = localStorage.getItem('user_id');
    console.log (this.booking.order_id);
    const body = {
      id: ,
      sprayer_id: user_id,
    };
}
```

However if you need a high level copy of the booking.order_id inside the component class, you could first create a variable in the component:

```
order_id;
```

Then in you're method do something like this:

```
getOrderid(order_id?: any){
  this.order_id = order_id;
  console.log (order_id);
}
```

And you can access that inside the `signupdatebooking()` method:

```
signupdatebooking() {
    var user_id = localStorage.getItem('user_id');
    console.log (this.order_id);
    const body = {
      id: ,
      sprayer_id: user_id,
    };
}
```